# How can I use datetime_field with HAML?

Tags: haml, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use [datetime_field](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-datetime_field) from Rails 4 in my views.

```
= f.datetime_field :scheduled_at
```

I was hoping to be getting pretty pop-up a-la JQuery as shown [here](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/new-html5-form-input-helpers-rails-4-countdown-to-2013).

I am getting the output below and a regular text input field in the browser

```
<input class="span2" id="appendedInput" name="appointment[scheduled_at]" type="datetime">
```

NB I am using HAML and not ERB. Has anyone been successfull with the combination of Ruby 2, Rails 4, datetime_field and HAML?

- actionpack (4.0.0.rc2)
- haml (4.0.3)
- rails (4.0.0.rc2)
- railties (4.0.0.rc2)

I hope I am missing something obvious ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DNNX pointed me in the right direction.

Turns out that most browsers don't yet support "datetime" type. At the moment, I could get the expected output with Opera only. "date" type is better supported and Chrome, Opera and Maxthon are displaying "date" type right.

Here is a link to the supported input types, http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type

Answer (score 1):

The HAML output looks fine. Probably, your browser has incomplete support of HTML5, or your html document is not html5 (double-check the doctype).

I've tried your html on this page - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date - it works just as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried Chrome, Firefox and Safari, all the latest versions, all giving the same blank text input field. Moreover, the link you have provided opens to the same blank text input field. BTW, in your example you use date type, while I am getting datetime type generated.

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction. Turns out that most browsers don't yet support "datetime" type. At the moment, I could get the expected output with Opera only. "date" type is better supported and Chrome, Opera and Maxthon are displaying it right.